# get id of form being submitted

Tags: javascript, forms

[I posted a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465212/cant-submit-generated-form) wrt dynamically created forms, and got excellent advice. At the moment I have a list of forms, formCELL, each created as follows.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-element" id="1">
        <h3>HEADER</h3>
        <form action="refresh.php" id="formCELL" method="post" name="form_1">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-10 com">
                    CONTENT GOES HERE
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh" type="submit">Refresh</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container-element" id="2">
        <h3>HEADER</h3>
        <form action="refresh.php" id="formCELL" method="post" name="form_2">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-10 com">
                    CONTENT GOES HERE
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh" type="submit">Refresh</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container-element" id="3">
        <h3>HEADER</h3>
        <form action="refresh.php" id="formCELL" method="post" name="form_3">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-10 com">
                    CONTENT GOES HERE
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh" type="submit">Refresh</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container-element" id="4">
        <h3>HEADER</h3>
        <form action="refresh.php" id="formCELL" method="post" name="form_4">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-10 com">
                    CONTENT GOES HERE
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh" type="submit">Refresh</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#formMAIN').submit(function(event) {

       //formCELL is generated here through AJAX call.....

   });
});

$('#formCELL').submit(function(event) {

    // process the form
    alert("about to submit");
    //AJAX call to go here

    var user_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');   
    alert(user_id);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am trying to get the id of the form being submitted so I can process it further, and I've tried diferent variations of $(this).closest("form").attr('id'); and all return a value of **undefined**

How can I get the id of the form being submitted?

Comment: you (edit: WILL) need to post the html for this

Comment: ok, you have answers; ask them.

Comment: sorry, i've edited the original post.

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique. You have 2 forms bearing the same ID. You want to use a class if you want to go further with this. However, you didn't name one of the forms `formMAIN`, you called them both `formCELL`, that's why it's not working. Let me know if you want this as an "answer".

Comment: Hey - I noticed the issue with the id's when I was updating the original post - I've since set the form class to formCELL, and the id to "frm1", "frm2" etc.

event.target.id returns the id of the form, but I presumed I could just navigate through siblings and parent divs to update various elements.

Comment: @Fred -ii- As was suggested below, I used event.target.id to get the id of the form. So now, to get various attributes of the parent div, I'm using the following:

    var user_id = event.target.closest('div').id;
                
    var score = $('div #' + user_id +'').attr('data-score');
    var time = $('div #' + user_id +'').attr('data-time');
                
    alert(score);
    alert(time);

is this way of navigating through elements on the page acceptable? I know it 'works', but it seems convoluted. Am I missing a simpler way?

Comment: Great, glad to see you found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target.id` to get form id

Comment: ie 6-8 uses `event.srcElement` instead of `event.target.id`

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the "submit" event to whole form and then use

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use data-id bro .
Put data-id as attribute in form
So you can easily get it using 
$(this).attr('data-id')